# Ошибка с string

Tags: компилятор, visual-studio, c++, компиляция

Здравствуйте. Недавно начал копать С++ и просто решив поэкспериментировать написал следующий код:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
 std::string text;
 std::cout << "Enter text: ";
 std::cin >> text;
 std::cout << "Text : " << text;
}
```

После чего среда написала возле каждого `<<` и `>>`, где находилась переменная `text`, следующее:

> Error: отсутствует оператор "<<", соответствующий этим операндам

Я не придал этому значение и откомпилировал. После чего компилятор выдал мне страшную ошибку. Вот одна только первая её строчка (всю писать я не стал ибо очень большая):

> [путь]code\code.cpp(10): error C2678: бинарный ">>": не найден оператор, принимающий левый операнд типа "std::istream" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)
>
> [путь]\include\istream(1053): может быть "std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator >>>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,signed char *)
>
> [путь]code\code.cpp(10): error C2678: бинарный ">>": не найден      оператор, принимающий левый операнд типа "std::istream" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)
>
> [путь]include\istream(1053): может быть "std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator >>>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,signed char *)"`

`[путь]` — путь к корневой папке студии или проекта.

Вопрос: Где у меня ошибка и что я сделал неправильно? И конечно же как это исправить?

Comment: Ваш текст, скомпилированный g++ нормально компилируется и выполняется. Даже если ри трансляции задать параметр -pedantic -- принимать только стандартные конструкции. gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <string>
```